# Magento don't see a product in backend

Tags: php, magento

I have a small script in magento to get product with sku.

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$itemsku);
```

Now, I try if the product exist:

```
 if(!$product){
array_push($productnotbd,$itemsku);
 } else {
    var_dump($product);
 }

 var_dump($productnotbd);
```

I confirm that the product exist but I try to find in back-end,
and I didn't see. But it's only for some product and not entire products.

I have more than 7 000 products.

Any idea?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Is the product active? Are you using multi store? Where is this script be run form (admin, frontend or external file)?

Comment: Admin function. into the IndexAction().
But Yes the problem is that my product don't have a status (empty status). I guess...

Comment: What class do indexAction extends?

Comment: this class extends the Adminhtml controller -> Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action